# Excluir ou alterar dados do sql usando php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-update

Estou criando uma página onde será feito o upload de algumas informações, e essas informações serão transferidas para um banco de dados e exibidas nessa mesma pagina, conforme abaixo:[image: captura]

Conforme destacado em azul, criei uma lista com opções que o usuário poderá escolher x ações e alterar os dados exibidos.

**Mas minha principal dúvida consiste em: como, por exemplo, excluir uma linha do banco de dados, usando a checkbox?**

Tentei vários tutorias, mas todos sem sucesso.

Na página, usei estes códigos para importar, armazenar e exibir os dados:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

  //get the csv file 
  $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
  $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

  //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
  do { 
      if ($data[0]) { 
          mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `pedidos` (`emissaoPed`, `nPedido`, `pedCliente`, `nomeAbrev`, `vlr`, `status`) VALUES 
              ( 
                  '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                  '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
                  '".addslashes($data[2])."',
                  '".addslashes($data[3])."',
                  '".addslashes($data[4])."',
                  '".addslashes($data[5])."'
              ) 
          "); 
      } 
  } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 
} 

?> 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
<title>Import a CSV File with PHP & MySQL</title> 
</head> 

<body> 

<?php if (!empty($_GET[success])) { echo "<b>Your file has been imported.</b><br><br>"; } //generic success notice ?> 

  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 
    Choose your file: <br /> 
    <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" /> 
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 
  </form> 
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form2" id="form2"> 
    <label>Selecione o status:</label>
    <select name="changePed">
      <option value="separacao">Em Separação</option>
      <option value="cancelado">Cancelado</option>
      <option value="faturado">Faturado</option>
      <option value="exp">Expedido</option>
  </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Alterar">
  </form>
<?php
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `pedidos`");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th><input type='checkbox' name='select-all' id='select-all' /></th>
<th>Data de emissão</th>
<th>EMS</th>
<th>Pedido do  cliente</th>
<th>Cliente</th>
<th>Valor do pedido</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox'></td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['emissaoPed'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['nPedido'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['pedCliente'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['nomeAbrev'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['vlr'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: colocando como valor na checkbox o id ou qq identificador exclusivo dessa linha

Comment: Sua tabela tem alguma coluna que identifique a linha como exclusiva? um id auto increment?

Comment: Olá Leo, obrigado por responde? Você diz a tabela no mysql? Sim, ela possui uma coluna id com auto increment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

1 - coloque como valor na checkbox  `name='checkbox[]'` o id da seguinte forma

`value='. $row['id']`

2 - transfira a tag de fechamento  `</form>` do segundo formulário para depois da tag de fechamento  `</table>`

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 
    Choose your file: <br /> 
    <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" /> 
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form> 
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form2" id="form2"> 
    <label>Selecione o status:</label>
    <select name="changePed">
      <option value="separacao">Em Separação</option>
      <option value="cancelado">Cancelado</option>
      <option value="faturado">Faturado</option>
      <option value="exp">Expedido</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" value="Alterar">

<?php
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `pedidos`");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th><input type='checkbox' name='select-all' id='select-all' /></th>
<th>Data de emissão</th>
<th>EMS</th>
<th>Pedido do  cliente</th>
<th>Cliente</th>
<th>Valor do pedido</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' value=" . $row['id'] . "></td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['emissaoPed'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['nPedido'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['pedCliente'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['nomeAbrev'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['vlr'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

**PHP**

> como o nome dos checkbox estão com colchetes no fim, o php irá reconhecer como um array e portanto pode-se usar

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
    $arr = filter( $_POST['checkbox'] );
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM pedidos WHERE id IN('.implode( ',', $arr ).')';
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
}
function filter( $dados ){
    $arr = Array();
    foreach( $dados AS $dado ) $arr[] = (int)$dado;
    return $arr;
}
```

<sub>Sómente uma OBS: Na maioria dos casos, você não vai precisar usar esse atributo  `enctype="multipart/form-data"` em tudo. O valor padrão (ou seja, se você não usar esse atributo em todos) é "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" , que é suficiente para quase qualquer tipo de dados do formulário. No caso de upload de arquivos, você deve usar "multipart/form-data"</sub>

Comment: Leo, obrigado pela disposição de novo! Mas o php.ini aponta um erro que eu já estava caindo. Ao incluir no value da chekbox a o id, ele aponta o seguinte erro

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /home/sites/2a/9/98b6f35433/public_html/attpedidos.php on line 103
A linha 103 é a seguinte: 
  echo "<td><input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' value='. $row['id'] .'></td>";

Comment: corrigi essa linha para não dar esse erro

Comment: Leo, uma dica: utilizar o `foreach` executará inúmeras operacões no banco de dados e isso pode ser espendioso para a aplicacão. Alternativamente, você pode excluir todos os registros desejados fazendo `DELETE FROM pedidos WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, ...)`. No caso, com PHP, você pode utilizar a funcão `$excluir = implode(",", $_POST["checkbox"])` para gerar uma string no formato `1, 2, 3` e passar na query  `"DELETE FROM pedidos WHERE id IN ({$excluir})"`, por exemplo.

Comment: E geralmente utilizar o `checkbox` no cabecalho da tabela é para aumentar a usabilidade, de forma que o usuário consiga selecionar todos os registros de uma vez ou desselecionar os que estão selecionados. Isso seria feito com JavaScript, no caso. Não afeta a sua solucão, mas achei que fosse válido comentar dada a sua dica 1 na resposta.

Comment: Leo e @AndersonCarlosWoss, vocês salvaram meu projeto, obrigado pela ajuda! :D Funcionou perfeitamente. Creio que a partir daqui eu consiga me virar ^^